# python pandas dataframe groupby put same group together

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas data frame `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'v1': ['b', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'f', 'e'], 
                          'v2': ['a', 'a', 'd', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'c', 'd', 'g','c'],
                          'v3': [3.3, 2.9, 3.5, 4.7, 5.1, 1.1, 2.3, 3.4, 4.7, 6.1]})
    v1  v2  v3
0   b   a   3.3
1   b   a   2.9
2   c   d   3.5 
3   a   b   4.7
4   d   c   5.1
5   c   e   1.1
6   d   c   2.3
7   c   d   3.4
8   f   g   4.7
9   e   c   6.1
```

I want to generate result looks like:

```
    v1  v2  v3
0   b   a   3.3
1   b   a   2.9
3   a   b   4.7
2   c   d   3.5 
4   d   c   5.1
6   d   c   2.3
7   c   d   3.4
5   c   e   1.1
9   e   c   6.1
8   f   g   4.7
```

i.e., stack rows with the same pairs of `v1` and `v2`.

`v1 = a, v2 = b` and `v1 = b, v2 = a` is not equal(we cannot swap `v1` and `v2`) but they are regarded as in the same group. How can I make it?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Option 1

```
df.loc[sorted(df.index, key=lambda i: tuple(sorted(df.loc[i, ['v1', 'v2']])))]

  v1 v2   v3
0  b  a  3.3
1  b  a  2.9
3  a  b  4.7
2  c  d  3.5
4  d  c  5.1
6  d  c  2.3
7  c  d  3.4
5  c  e  1.1
9  e  c  6.1
8  f  g  4.7
```

---

### Option 2

Probably more intuitive but likely slower as well due to lots of apply.

```
df.reindex(df.apply(frozenset, 1).apply(tuple).sort_values().index)

  v1 v2   v3
0  b  a  3.3
1  b  a  2.9
3  a  b  4.7
2  c  d  3.5
4  d  c  5.1
6  d  c  2.3
7  c  d  3.4
5  c  e  1.1
9  e  c  6.1
8  f  g  4.7
```

---

### Option 3

```
a = np.empty(len(df), object)
a[:] = list(map(sorted, zip(df.v1, df.v2)))
df.iloc[np.argsort(a)]

  v1 v2   v3
0  b  a  3.3
1  b  a  2.9
3  a  b  4.7
2  c  d  3.5
4  d  c  5.1
6  d  c  2.3
7  c  d  3.4
5  c  e  1.1
9  e  c  6.1
8  f  g  4.7
```

Comment: I prefer the first, because of the lack of apply.

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks.

Comment: All correct! Option 3 is very fast. I test 10000 times using some real data (**option 3: 2s**, option 1: ~20s, I did not test option 2, the other solution: ~8s). Thanks much!

Answer (score 4):

In similar fashion, use `argsort`:

```
df.iloc[pd.Series(
    [tuple(x) for x in np.sort(df.iloc[:, :2], axis=1)]).argsort()
]

  v1 v2   v3
0  b  a  3.3
1  b  a  2.9
3  a  b  4.7
2  c  d  3.5
4  d  c  5.1
6  d  c  2.3
7  c  d  3.4
5  c  e  1.1
9  e  c  6.1
8  f  g  4.7
```

Comment: @jezrael Oh is it? Okay, give me a few minutes. I will edit my answer to include that information. It is an important case so I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: @jezrael yeah your answer is fine, no need to delete in this case. I will add the link.

Comment: @jezrael That's not how this site works. If you are using external context to answer a question, that means there is a problem and the question is incomplete lacking a [mcve] and should be closed instead of mindlessly pandering for points. I don't get what is happening here but I really dislike it.

Comment: @jezrael yeah but the problem was that OP did not even think we were worth his time to at least tell us that it was wrong. It was easier to send you a mail instead and ask you to answer and get points for it. I won't say it's wrong or unfair, just not sportsmanlike.

Comment: Okay sure, whatever the case may be. I hope you understand where I'm coming from. The right thing to do would have been to ping me and tell me the error. I would have understood what was the problem and corrected it. Instead of pinging you in chat. This is because of the perception you have built over the years that no one else's answer is worth anything except yours. Again, hope you understand where I'm coming from

Comment: No hard feelings, I get it will happen now and then, but I can't say I approve of it

Comment: Yes, I try explain it because frind, what is problem, also say OP for using comments if some problem with answers.